# Show that the number $n$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove that $n = 8709120$ divisible by $7$?
I have tried a couple methods, but I can't show that. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of performing the division?

Comment: http://www.aaamath.com/div66_x7.htm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7

Comment: Because 1001 is divisible by $7$, we see that the remainders (when divided by $7$) of $8709120$ and $8-709+120=-581$ agree. But $581=490+7\cdot13$ is divisible by $7$, so...

Comment: I can't believe that 100k+ member's first reaction is not to look for a duplicate :-(

Comment: Just 10 answers?

Comment: \begin{align}
870912 - 2\times 0&=870912
\\
87091 - 2\times 2&=87087
\\
8708 - 2\times 7&=8694
\\
869 - 2\times 4&=861
\\
86 - 2\times 1&=84
\\
8 - 2\times 4&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

First, you can subtract 7 from the large digits.  8-7=1 and so on, so you are left with $1002120$.
Then, it is true that 1001 is a multiple of 7.  So subtract 1001000 from the number, and you have 1120.
Lastly, divide 7 into 112 using short division.

Answer (score 4):

This is equivalent to $1002120$ is divisible by $7$.

As $7|98$, this is equivalent to
$22120$ is divisible by $7$, or
$1120$ is divisible by 7.

It is true as $112 = 98 + 14 = 7\times 14 + 7\times 2$.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the following.

> 8709120 is divisible by 7 iff
>
> 870912 is divisible by 7  iff
>
> 100212 is divisible by 7  iff
>
> 112 is divisible by 7 (because 1001 is divisible by 7) iff
>
> 42 is divisible by 7

Answer (score 2):

The Divisibility test for 7 is:

A number of the form $10x + y$ is divisible by 7 if and only if $x − 2y$ is divisible by 7, where $y$ is a numeral (0-9).

Knowing this, we can apply the divisibility test onto 8709120. We iterate multiple times to find a small enough number

First Iteration: $870912$

Second Iteration: $87091-4=87087$

Third Iteration: $8708-14=8694$

Third Iteration: $869-8=861$

Third Iteration: $86-2=84$

$84=7\times12$, so we can conclude that $8709120$ is divisible by 7

Answer (score 1):

As $21x-2(10x+y)=x-2y\implies7\mid(10x+y)\iff 7|(x-2y)$

Similarly, $5(10x+y)-49x=x+5y\implies7\mid(10x+y)\iff 7|(x+5y)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $7\cdot 13=91$, we only need to prove that $1000020$, or $100002$, is divisible by $7$:
$$ 10^5+2 \equiv 3^{-1}+2\pmod{7} \equiv 0\pmod{7},$$
since $3\cdot 5\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, or just because $2+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\color{red}{7}}{3}.$

Answer (score 1):

First, note that

$$
1 \equiv 1 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10 \equiv 3 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10^2 \equiv 2 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10^3 \equiv -1 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10^4 \equiv -3 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10^5 \equiv -2 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
10^6 \equiv 1 (\bmod 7)
$$

$$
\ldots
$$

So, if the number $n$ has these digits: $n = \overline{...d_7 d_6d_5d_4d_3d_2d_1d_0}$, then
$$
n  \equiv 1\cdot (d_0 - d_3 + d_6 - d_9 + ...) \\
+ 3\cdot (d_1 - d_4 + d_7 - d_{10} + ...) \\
+ 2\cdot (d_2 - d_5 + d_8 - d_{11} + ...) \\
(\bmod 7)
$$

It is easy to apply this test:

$$
8709120 \bmod 7 \equiv 1\cdot (0-9+8) + 3\cdot (2-0) + 2\cdot (1-7) = -1+6-12 = -7 \equiv 0 (\bmod 7) 
$$

Hence, $8709120$ is divisible by $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Without wasting any thoughts on whether it was $101$ or $1001$ or ... that is a multiple of $7$, repeatedly subtract obvious multiples of $7$:
$$ \underline 8\underline70\underline9120 \to \underline{10}0\underline{21}20\to \underline{30}0020\to\underline{20}020\to\underline{60}20\to\underline{42}0\to 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known test for the divisibility of a number by $7$.

$a_k\dots a_1a_0$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $a_2a_1a_0-a_5a_4a_3+a_8a_7a_6-\dots$ is divisible by $7$.

So split $8709120$ into groups $008,709,120$.

Then calculate $008-709+120=-581$.

$-581\div7=-83\implies8709120$ is divisible by $7$.

For the record, I have asked a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918317/131263) once, and I used the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/919015/131263) I got to answer yours.

Answer (score 1):

1) $8709120=7000000+1709120$

2) $1709120=1400000+309120$

3) $309120=280000+29120$

4) $29120=28000+1120$

5) $1120=700+420$,

$8709120=7000000+1400000+280000+28000+700+420$ is divisible by $7$.