# Is $1010908899$ divisible by $7$ , $11$ and $13$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So the given number is **$1010908899$** and I showed that it is divisible by $11$ since $9-9+8-8+0-9+0-1+0-1=-11$ which is divisible by $11$ hence the number also. But how to check if it is also divisible by $7$ and $13$?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/919015/131263). If I'm not mistaken, then you do it for each one of these factors in the same way you did it for $11$, but in groups of $3$ digits instead of $1$ (so in the example above, you check $101-090+889-9\color\red{00}$).

Comment: If you don't need to do it by hand then factor the number using an online tool. $1010908899 = 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 101^2 $

Comment: ... or just use long division.

Comment: I want to do it in number theory way, using general results.

Comment: I have a divisibility test for 7 . If you want to find out whether a number is divisible by 7 or not then just square the last digit of the number and subtract it from the remaining number  . If the number is divisible by 7 then the original number is also divisible . so here last digits is 9 so $9^2$=81 so remaining number - the square=101090889-81=101090808  which is divisible by 7 ( by calculator) thus the number 1010908899 is too divisible by 7. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $7$, $11$, and $13$ are prime numbers, a number is divisible by $7$, $11$, and $13$ if and only if it is divisible by $7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 = 1001$.

Comment: And the number is divisible by $1001$ if $1-010+908-899$ is divisible by $1001$.

Answer (score 3):

The test I've seen for divisibility by $7$ is to chop off the one's digit, multiply by 2, and subtract from the number that was left over. Keep going until you get an answer that is obviously (or obviously not) a multiple of $7$. Thus $$\begin{array}{lll} 1010908899 &\to &101090889 - 18 = 101090871 \\
101090871 & \to & 10109087 - 2 = 10109085 \\
10109085 & \to & 1010908 - 10 = 1010898 \\
1010898 & \to & 101089 - 16 = 101073 \\
101073 &\to & 10107 - 6 = 10101 \\
10101 &\to & 1010 - 2 = 1008 \\
1008 &\to & 100 - 16 = 84 \\
84 &\to & 8 - 8 = 0
\end{array} $$

Since $0$ is a multiple of $7$, so was $1010908899$. This isn't really a practical way to do it, but it is kind of interesting.

---

A similar test for divisibility by $13$ is to chop off the one's digit, multiply by $4$, then add to the number that was left over. In the case of your number, $$\begin{array}{lll} 1010908899 &\to &101090889 +36 = 101090925 \\
101090925 & \to & 10109092 + 20 = 10109112 \\
10109112 & \to & 1010911 +8 = 1010919 \\
1010919 & \to & 101091 + 36 = 101127 \\
101127 &\to & 10112 +28 = 10140 \\
10140 &\to & 1014 + 0  = 1014 \\
1014 &\to & 101 + 16 = 117 \\
117 &\to & 11  +28 = 39 \\
39 &\to & 3 + 36 = 39
\end{array} $$
which repeats indefinitely, but $39$ is a multiple of $13$, and thus so is $1010908899$.

Comment: You don't need to go quite so far, because $999999$ is divisible by $7$, so you can first take the sum of ever group of six digits: $908899+1010$. You can then apply the double-and-subtract.

Comment: I'm upping one because I think this is a simple divisibility rule that should be better known  - and definitely more often taught in schools. Instead, we're often taught there's no easy divisibility rule for $7$. By the way, the reason this works is that we're transforming $100x + 10y + z$ into $10x + y - 2z$. Modulo $7$, the former is $2x + 3y + z$ and the latter is $3x + y - 2z$. If the latter is a multiple of $7$, $y = 2z - 3x \pmod 7$. Substituting that back into the former gives $10x -3x = 7x = 0 \pmod 7$. So divisibility of the "reduced" form implies divisibility of the original.

Comment: I only covered the rule for $7$, but one could see why the rule for $13$ works the way it does using similar methods.

Comment: @Deepak it is somewhat simpler than that: $10x + y \equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$ implies $30x + 3y \equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$ implies $-20 x - 2y \equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$ implies $x - 2y \equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$ and vice versa, since 21 is a multiple of 7.

Answer (score 2):

General results:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 10^n & 10^n \bmod 7 & 10^n \bmod 11 & 10^n \bmod 13 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 10 & 3 & -1 & -3 \\
2 & 10^2 & 2 & 1 & -4 \\
3 & 10^3 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
4 & 10^4 & -3 & 1 & 3 \\
5 & 10^5 & -2 & -1 & 4 \\ \hline
6 & 10^6 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
7 & 10^7 & 3 & -1 & -3 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots 
\end{array}
$$

So, the number $$...d_7d_6d_5d_4d_3d_2d_1d_0$$ is divisible by $7$, iff
$$(1,3,2,-1,-3,-2,\; 1,3,...)\cdot(d_0,d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6,d_7,...)\equiv 0(\bmod 7),$$
is divisible by $11$, iff
$$(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\; 1,-1,...)\cdot(d_0,d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6,d_7,...)\equiv 0(\bmod 11),$$
is divisible by $13$, iff
$$(1,-3,-4,-1,3,4,\; 1,-3,...)\cdot(d_0,d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6,d_7,...)
\equiv 0(\bmod 11).$$

Here we use dot product: $(u_0,u_1,u_2,...)\cdot (v_0,v_1,v_2,...) = u_0v_0+u_1v_1+u_2v_2+...$.

So, on divisibility by $7$: 
$1010908899 \equiv (1,3,2,-1,-3,-2,1,3,2,-1)\cdot (9,9,8,8,0,9,0,1,0,1)=28\equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$,

 on divisibility by $11$: 
$1010908899 \equiv (1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)\cdot (9,9,8,8,0,9,0,1,0,1)=-11\equiv 0 (\bmod 11)$,

 on divisibility by $13$: 
$1010908899 \equiv (1,-3,-4,-1,3,4,1,-3,-4,-1)\cdot (9,9,8,8,0,9,0,1,0,1)=-26\equiv 0 (\bmod 13)$.

Comment: could any tell if this approach is applicable to higher value numbers as well?